# How does WCF RIA Services handle authentication/authorization/security?

Tags: ajax, security, authentication, authorization, wcf-ria-services

Since no one answered this question:

[What issues to consider when rolling your own data-backend for Silverlight / AJAX on non-ASP.NET server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2439473/what-issues-to-consider-when-rolling-your-own-data-backend-for-silverlight-ajax)

Let me ask it another way:

**How does WCF RIA Services handle authentication/authorization/security at a low level?**

- e.g. how does the application on the server determine that the **incoming http request** to change data is coming from a **valid client** and not from non-desirable source, e.g. a denial-of-service bot?

Answer (score 1):

From my investigation, all calls into the RIA service classes are forced through a custom IOperationInvoker class (enforced by a custom IOperationBehavior class).  This invoker calls into DomainService to have the operation executed.

Before it is executed, the method call is validated any/all AuthorizationAttribute attributes marked on the operation in question.  Each AuthorizationAttribute (two provided are RequiresAuthenticationAttribute & RequiresRoleAttribute) is given an opportunity to accept or reject the call via the abstract IsAuthorized method.

If any of these attributes returns something other than "AuthorizationResult.Allowed", an UnauthorizedAccessException exception is thrown with the ErrorMessage from the AuthorizationResult returned.